# Let $A \unlhd G$ and $o(x) = 3$ for each $x \notin A$, then $[B, B^x] = 1$ for abelian subgoups $B \le A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

> Let $A$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. If each element from $G \setminus A$ has order $3$, then $[B, B^x] = 1$ for every abelian subgroup $B \le A$ and $x \in G \setminus A$.

Any hints for this exercise? I have totally no idea how to exploit the fact that $x$ has order three (guess this might be crucial here...). All I see is that $B^x \le A$ by normality of $A$ and that we must show $[b, \hat b^x] = 1$ for $b, \hat b \in B$.

Comment: Since $B$ is abelian, any two elements in it must commute with each other, so the commutator equals 1...am I missing something?

Comment: @Nishant: Yes, $B^x \ne B$ in general, so $b^x$ and $b$ need not commute in general. But $B^x \le A$ by normality. So we cannot apply the presupposition about the order of elements to the elements in any conjugate of $B$.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $b \in B$, $1 = (xb)^3 = x^3b^{x^2}b^xb=b^{x^{-1}}b^xb$, so $b^{-1}=b^{x^{-1}}b^x$ (1).

For some other element $c \in B$, conjugating (1) by $c$ (which commutes with $b$) gives $b^{-1} = b^{x^{-1}c}b^{xc}$.

But we could also replace $x$ by $c^{-1}x$ in (1), giving $b^{-1} = b^{x^{-1}c}b^{c^{-1}x} = b^{x^{-1}c}b^{x}$, so $b^{xc}=b^{x}$,
and hence $c$ commutes with $b^{x}$.

Comment: I am impressed how fluently and easily you manipulate such complicated expressions (also in my other question on commutators), do you have any intuition connected with them or is it just practice and genius?

Comment: I have shortened the last step slightly. I just tried to make use of the assumptions. What is the source or motivation for this problem? The hypothesis of every element outside of $A$ having order $3$ seems strange.

Comment: Yes indeed. Unluckily I have no context, it is exercise 1.5.6. in Kurzweil/Stellmacher *Theory of Finite Groups*. They refer to Burnside's book *Theory of groups of finite order*, I looked it up but could not find it in this book, the first edition is available here: https://archive.org/details/theorygroupsfin00burngoog

Comment: There are groups of infinite exponent with a whole coset of index 2 consisting of elements of order 2 (e.g., $O(2)$). So I think it's natural to wonder about this kind of phenomena.