# Abelian subgroup contained in a normal subgroup; a trick about elements of order $3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $A$ be a ***normal subgroup*** of $G$. Suppose that every element in $G\,\backslash\, A$ has ***order*** $\bf 3$. Then $[B,B^x]=1$ for all ***Abelian subgroups***  $B\leq A$ and $x\in G\,\backslash\, A$.

I have been told that my task must have something to do with Chapter VI, *On the isomorphism of a Group with Itself*, para 66. of the famous book—“Burnside, W.: *Theory of Groups of Finite Order*, 2nd edn., Cambridge 1911; Dover Publications, New York 1955”. **[ It’s a trick about order $3$, which was mentioned in the comments and Derek Holt’s answer below. ]**

Although we‘ve made many attempts indeed and have made a breakthrough (Derek Holt’s answer), yet we haven’t been able to figure out **how to use the normality of** $A$ **and abelianity of** $ B$, on which I’m still struggling...

It would be greatly appreciated if you are kind enough to provide a reasonable answer!

**PS:** It’s exercise 1.5.6 of the book [*The Theory of Finite Groups, An Introduction*](http://www.math.ku.dk/~olsson/manus/GruFus/Kurzweil-Stellmacher_Theory%20of%20finite%20groups.pdf). Berlin: Springer, 2004.

Comment: Do you mean $G/A$ rather than $G\setminus A$?

Comment: $G/A$ is usually used to denote the factor group. $G\setminus A$ is the complement of $A$.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, I’ve edited it : ) and what can I get from order $3$?

Comment: @Arthur It is not possible for every element of a group to have order $3$. I would guess that $G \setminus A$ is what is intended.

Comment: @DerekHolt yes! It’s $G\setminus A$.

Comment: @DerekHolt You're right. I just thought that 1) it's easy to lose "non-identity" in a phrase like that if you're not careful, and 2) since $A$ is normal, $G/A$ is generally a lot more common to consider than $G\setminus A$. They could well mean the complement here, but I just wanted to be certain.

Comment: Sorry, that’s my fault...

Comment: Page 90 of Burnside contains his celebrated treatment of finite groups with fixed-point-free automorphisms of order 2 (they are abelian) or of order 3 (they are direct products of their Sylow subgroups, he references his paper Proc LMS XXXV (1902) pp 28 - 37). It is a very long time since I struggled with this page. I will add what I think is the crucial argument in a moment.

Comment: In this context fixed point free means "apart from 1"

Comment: This, if I recall, is the crucial part of Burnside's argument. If $a\in A$ and $x\not\in A$ then $a a^x a^{x^2}=(a x^2)^3=1$ and so $a a^{x^2} a^x=a  a^{x^2} a^{x^4}=1$, so that $a^x$ and $a^{x^2}$ commute; similarly $a$ and $a^x$ commute.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks a lot! I got an access but the page numbers doesn’t match, because that has been typeset in Latex, which is not the original version. Is that in chapter VII— *On Abelian Groups* ?

Comment: It has to be the 2nd edition. It is Chapter VI, On the Isomorphism of a group with itself, It is para 66.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Excuse me, what does Burnside mean by $S$ in permutations, for example $\binom{S}{S’}$. I’m not familiar with his denotations.

Comment: I think by this he just means the permutation carries the group element $S$ [traditionally, a "substitution"] to the group element $S'$.

Comment: I can show that $[b,b^x] = 1$ for all $b \in A$ and $x \in G \setminus A$, but that's not enough.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you! I’d be grateful if I could know how you do it.

Comment: If you really quite a beginner at group theory, then I am surprised that you are attempting to solve such a difficult problem!

Comment: @DerekHolt : ) Thanks for your answer. I’ve learned abstract-algebra for a couple of months as an undergraduate, but I have been teaching myself group-theory just for a couple of weeks. It is this website that helps me so much!

Comment: One more thought: Bernhard Neumann wrote on this sort of thing, perhaps showed the nilpotence class of groups with fpf auto of order 3 was 2? I can't trace the reference, alas: just dug out my 1967 thesis to see if I used it, but no luck.

Comment: The reference I meant is Arch. Math. (1956) pp 1--5. It is referenced in Gorenstein's book, chapter 10, where he does this sort of thing. This may be worth a look.

Comment: @ancientmathematician : ) I’d be thankful to be given a link. Do you have one?

Comment: Alas, no. I only have hard copy of Gorenstein's book.

Comment: I think that the Burnside trick (as you call it) lets one prove that $\langle B,B^x\rangle$ is fixed by $x$. Moreover I think it lets one prove $BB^{x}=BB^{x^2}$(*); and then $B^x B=B^{x}(B^{x})^{x^2}=B^x B^{x^2}=B B^{x^2} B^{x^2}=B B^{x^2}=B B^{x}$ by repeated use of (*) and the trick. Now without loss of generality one can assume $A=B B^x$, $G=A\langle x\rangle$. I note that one is then in the same situation as the previous exercise, the Ito one. I am now stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but I hope it helps.

Let $b \in A$ and $x \in G \setminus A$. We claim that $b$ commutes with $b^x = x^{-1}bx$.

Let $u = bx^{-1}bx$ and $v = x^{-1}bxb$. We want to show that $u=v$.

Now, since $b\in A,\,x\not\in A\Rightarrow bx^{-1}\not\in A\Rightarrow(bx^{-1})^3=1$, we have $(bx^{-1})^2u = bx$.

Similarly, using $x^{-2}=x$ and $(bx)^3=1$, we get $(bx^{-1})^2v = bx^{-1}bxbxb = bx^{-1}(bx)^3x^{-1} = bx^{-2} = bx$.

So $(bx^{-1})^2u = (bx^{-1})^2v$ and hence $u=v$, as claimed.

*Added March 20*: As Zach Teitler has pointed out, I had answered this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484993/). So I am afraid it is a duplicate.

Comment: Isn't this just Burnside's argument, @Derek ?

Comment: Yes it is. But we need to prove that $a$ commutes with $b^x$ for any $a,b \in A$ with $ab=ba$ and $x \in G \setminus A$, and I cannot think how to do that, although I suspect that must be some slick proof!

Comment: You see my comment on Neumann? -- do you remember the paper? I have a nagging feeling that's where it can be found.

Comment: I think we may have ignored $B$ is an abelian subgroup of $A$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician We don't know that an element of $G \setminus A$ acts fixed point freely on $A$ (in fact in easy examples such as $G$ elementary abelian, it need not), so how do you expect to use prooperties of such automorphisms

Comment: @benny No, we have not ignored that - I said that $ab=ba$ in my previous comment, but I have not been able to figure out how to use that.

Comment: @Derek Holt: The fixed points form a 3-group, so I have two cases ;-) . If I read Gorenstein aright there is for each $p$ a unique Sylow p-subgroup invariant under $x\not\in A$. But I am stuck.

Comment: But now that we can see where the problem comes in K & Stellmacher it must be much easier than I thought.

Comment: @DerekHolt Perhaps you have forgotten that you answered this in 2015: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484993/let-a-unlhd-g-and-ox-3-for-each-x-notin-a-then-b-bx-1-for-a :-)

Comment: @ZachTeitler  Yes I had forgotten, thanks! So the question is actually a duplicate.